# dropdown menu always shows below h1?

Tags: css

I have a dropdown menu and although i have set z-index to 999 on every possible element of it, the dropdown always shows below the h1.

Why would this happen?

This is in all browsers.

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Menu item</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Sub item 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Sub item 2</a></li>
            <li><a>Sub item 3</a></li>
            <li><a>Sub item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="article"><h1>Test title</h1></div>
```

The above is the html used
I have tried setting a z-index of 999 on all `<ul>'s <li>'s and <a>'s`

The sample css is the basic `display:block;` and `float: left;` where appropriate
`ul li ul` is set as `display: none` and is set as `display: block;` upon `ul li:hover`

however when the sub menu overlaps the `<h1>` the menu goes under it.

The menu is above the `<div id="article">` background color but below the text of the `<h1>`

Comment: please put some code to explain better.... does h1 have z-index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed). Also, additionaly to what Topera wrote, give bigger z-index value to menu's div or ul than h1.
The best would be if we had some code.

Answer (score 0):

The z-index:999 must be in the menu, not in all others elements.